# How c1 is taking this values in va_arg?

Tags: c, variables, variadic-functions, var

I am not understanding how c1 is printing 65, 66, 67, 68. I know how char c is printing A B C D, but how c1 has strange output?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdarg.h>
    void display(int num, ...);

    int main()
    {
      display(4, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
      return 0;
    }
    void display(int num, ...)
    {
      char c, c1; int j;
      va_list ptr, ptr1;
      va_start(ptr, num);
      va_start(ptr1, num);
      for(j=1; j<=num; j++)
       {
        c = va_arg(ptr, int);
        printf("%c", c);
        c1 = va_arg(ptr1, int);
        printf("%d\n", c1);
       }
     }
```

Comment: Are you asking about why `printf("%d\n", 'A');` prints 65? The title does not seem to have much to do with the question

Comment: In the ASCII character set `'A'` has a numeric value of `65`.   The `%d` format tells `printf()` to print the numeric value of an integral value.    So your code is providing exactly the output your have specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a strange output. You have mentioned the format specifier as "%d" in `printf("%d\n", c1);`. "%d" is the integer format specifier. So, the variable c1 is implicitly typecasted to an integer i.e ASCII value of the character. So in your case, it prints 'A' as 65, 'B' as 66 etc.

Refer to Conversion specifiers topic in [fprintf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html)

Comment: The W3Schools web sites do not have a good reputation on SO.  You might consider referencing the C standard (C11 [§7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)), or POSIX [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html), or maybe the Linux manual page [`fprintf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html), or …

Comment: I was not aware of that will update the links

Comment: The [page you linked to](https://www.w3schools.in/c-tutorial/format-specifiers/) lists 6 format specifiers for `printf()` — `%c`, `%s`, `%d`, `%u`, `%f`, `%ld`.  Granted that covers a fair number of the most important ones, but it is anything but comprehensive.  It misses hexadecimal, exponential notation for floating point, and `%p` for pointers.

Comment: or … —— There's also the C section of [https://en.cppreference.com/w/](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), and there's some C information at [https://www.cplusplus.com/), and there's the Microsoft documentation for [`fprintf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fprintf-fprintf-l-fwprintf-fwprintf-l?view=vs-2019), and the ISO C standards committee ([ISO JTC1 STC22 WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/), and [http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard).  Etc.